# Can install docker with yum on centos 7

Tags: docker, centos7, yum

I am following the steps shown [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#install-using-the-repository).

It says to setup a repository by calling:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

Then install by running:

```
sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

When I do that I get the following error:

> https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7Server/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found

When I go to that URL, it is a 404.  But I am unsure on what the correct URL should be and what to do to get it to use the correct URL.

I am open to any advice on how to get this working.

**Update:**
Exploring a bit more I found that this URL is probably the one I need to use:
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml

But I don't know how to get it to use that.

**Update 2:**
Downloading the file at https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo (from the first command) showed that it was getting the `7Server` value from a yum variable called `$releasever`.

This [page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-using_yum_variables) indicates that `$releasever` is read from /etc/yum.conf in the setting `distroverpkg`.  I added a line like this: `distroverpkg=7`.

But when I ran the install command again, `7Server` was replaced by `$releasever` directly (no substitution happened).  The `7` value I was looking for was not substituted in there.

Still stuck on how to get this to download and install docker.

**Update 3:**
I was able to add a file called `releasever` to /etc/yum/vars with the value of `7` in it.  When I ran the install command again, it found the repository correctly!

But then it needed to load another URL that broke.  It looked like that URL wanted `7Server` instead of `7` as the `releasever` variable.

Looks like I am out of luck :(

Comment: I think is something in your centos machine. In on-premise or cloud? I will try install docker in a docker centos container to replicate your error!

Comment: @JRichardsz - This is a VM running on-premise.

Comment: I just installed docker following your steps in a clean centos-7. There is no error. Check the log: https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/958dfca5350db490341ed01e446074c0. I added a readme with the steps

Answer (score 1):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1111) with download.docker.com that they have had open since September.

Basically they decided to retire the `7Server` urls.  They redirect to the plain `7` for the url https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7Server, but not for any deeper urls.

The workaround is to call this:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --setopt="docker-ce-stable.baseurl=https://download .docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable" --save
```

Before you call the `sudo yum install` command.

Answer (score 0):

do this for centos 7
go to cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
and delete all other repositories except centos related repositories.
goto docker official website and follow the install instructions again.
It works for me

Answer (score -1):

Due to the test on a fresh centos7, I think the problem is not docker.

Also if I search **repomd.xml** I found that is a commmon problem in centos when you try to install another tools:

**Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml)**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109585/yum-update-fails-error-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-re

As you will see in the question, the problem is related to rare behaviors in the centos s.o like: repos, certificates, updates, etc

Maybe this helps you:

```
yum clean all
yum check
yum erase apf
yum update ca-certificates
yum upgrade
```

Also If you don't want a headache, **delete your centos and create a new one!**